# How to count child nodes of XML?

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I have one XML like this ...

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<world>
  <country> 
      <name> France </name>  
      <city> Paris </city>
      <population> 3996 </population>
      <city> Lille </city>
      <state>NE</state>
      <zip> 000000 </zip>
   </country>
</world>
```

Here we can see that Tag Country has 6 child nodes .But how to calculate it Programmatically.
Your help will be appreciated..
Thanks in Advance....

Comment: See my answer, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below Code to Count child Nodes of NodeList, it will solve your problem.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/example.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("country");
int i=nodeList.getLength();
System.out.println("Total Child is:- " + i);
```

And See below link for more information about XML Parsing using Dom Parser.

[XML Parsing Using DOM Parser](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-%E2%80%93-using-domparser)

Answer (score 0):

To get the size of the set:

```
nl.getLength() //n1 is the object of NodeList

public int getLength()

The number of nodes in the list. The range of valid child node indices is 0 to length-1 inclusive.
```

and also take a look at [NODELIST](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html)